# Instance member 'linkButton' can't be accessed using static access

Tags: flutter, dart

**

I was developing a simple login page and ran into a strange error while working with data from an external file.

**

**на текущий момент проект содержит всего три файла main.dart, auth_widget.dart, app_button_style.dart**

main.dart :

```
`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:the_movie_db/widgets/auth/auth_widget.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 41, 41, 41),
        ),
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const AuthWidget(),
    );
  }
}`
```

auth_widget.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:the_movie_db/Theme/app_button_style.dart';

class AuthWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const AuthWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<AuthWidget> createState() => _AuthWidgetState();
}

class _AuthWidgetState extends State<AuthWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Login to Your Accaunt'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: const [
          _HeaderWidget(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _HeaderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const _HeaderWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.green);

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
      child: Column(
        children: const [
          SizedBox(
            height: 25,
          ),
          Text(
            'Welcome the Future',
            style: textStyle,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 25,
          ),
          Text(
            'The Macroeconomic Dao',
            style: textStyle,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 25,
          ),
          _FormWidget(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _FormWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const _FormWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<_FormWidget> createState() => _FormWidgetState();
}

class _FormWidgetState extends State<_FormWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const inputBorder = InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
      isCollapsed: true,
    );

    const textStyle =
        TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 48, 48, 48));

    const inputColor = Color(0xFF01B4E4);

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const Text(
          'User Name',
          style: textStyle,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
        const TextField(decoration: inputBorder),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        const Text(
          'Password',
          style: textStyle,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
        const TextField(
          decoration: inputBorder,
          obscureText: true,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              TextButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(inputColor),
                    foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),
                    textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                    padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 15, vertical: 8))),
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text('Login'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 30,
              ),
              TextButton(
                  style: const ButtonStyle(
                      foregroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(inputColor),
                      textStyle: MaterialStatePropertyAll(TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400))),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: const Text('Reset Password')),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 25,
        ),
        const Text('Or Sign up'),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
          child:
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Register')),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 25,
        ),
        const Text('If you signed up but didn`t get your verification email '),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
          child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              style: AppButtonStyle.linkButton,
              child: const Text('Register')),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

app_button_style.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

abstract class AppButtonStyle {
  final ButtonStyle linkButton = const ButtonStyle(
      foregroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Color(0xFF01B4E4)),
      textStyle: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
          TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)));
}
```

the cause of the error is not at all clear to me, tell me what could be the matter

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access linkButton like this (add brackets to AppButtonStyle)

```
style: AppButtonStyle().linkButton
```

This is because,

Only static variables can be accessed like this `AppButtonStyle.linkButton`.

If the variable is not static you should access it like this `AppButtonStyle().linkButton`.

If your class was not an AbstractClass, you could also have solved the issue by adding a static keyword before `final ButtonStyle linkButton = const ButtonStyle()` to make it `static final ButtonStyle linkButton = const ButtonStyle`.